# Tab function to improve.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that I need to run a tab (jquery). Mainly I need to hide some div and add class (you sure have understood).

How should it be written in a more elegant and readable?

```
function fun1(){
$('#tab1 a').addClass('selected');
$('#tab2 a').removeClass('selected');
$('#tab3 a').removeClass('selected');

document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
}
function fun2(){
$('#tab1 a').removeClass('selected');
$('#tab2 a').addClass('selected');
$('#tab3 a').removeClass('selected');

document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
}
function fun3(){
$('#tab1 a').removeClass('selected');
$('#tab2 a').removeClass('selected');
$('#tab3 a').addClass('selected');

document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div3').style.display='block';
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('tab1').onclick=fun1;
    document.getElementById('tab2').onclick=fun2;
    document.getElementById('tab3').onclick=fun3;

    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Switch from IDs to classes and you'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid repeating your code. How about a single function that will take care of everything:

```
function tab(id){

    $('#tab1').parent().children().removeClass('selected'); // remove selected class from all tabs
    $('#tab' + id).addClass('selected'); // add just to one we need

    $('#div1').parent().children().hide(); // hide all the #div elements
    $('#div' + id).show(); // show the one we need
}
```

Notes for the changes I made:

- `selected` class is now applied to #tab elements, not the anchors inside them
- I assumed all the #tabs and #divs are the only siblings within their containers
- to change the active tab, just call `tab(1)`, `tab(2)`, etc...

Here's a simple example with my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/CkpwT/1/

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
var tabs, divs;
function handler(n) {
    return function fun() {
        for(var i=0, l=tabs.length; i<l; ++i)
            tabs[i].find('a').toggleClass('selected', n==i);
        for(var i=0, l=divs.length; i<l; ++i)
            divs[i].toggle(n==i);
    };
}
window.onload = function() {
    tabs = [$('#tab1'), $('#tab2'), $('#tab3')];
    divs = [$('#div1'), $('#div2'), $('#div3')];
    for(var i=0, l=tabs.length; i<l; ++i)
        tabs[i].on('click', handler(i));
    tabs[0].click();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgkW6/)

Answer (score -1):

So, you have a tab for every page. And on click you want to also add a 'selected' class to the clicked element.

**[PLAYGROUND](http://jsbin.com/tuzup/4/edit)**

All you need is basically this simple HTML markup:

```
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="divs">
    <div>Div1</div>
    <div>Div2</div>
    <div>Div3</div>
  </div>
```

than you can simply get the `index` value of the clicked tab and open the same indexed `DIV` element:

```
$tabs = $('#tabs a'); // Cache your selectors
$divs = $('#divs > div');

$tabs.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent browser from following anchor href
  $tabs.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $divs.hide().eq( $tabs.index(this) ).show(); // Get the Tab element index and refer to the DIV using .eq()
}).eq(0).click();  // Trigger the initial click on a desired tab index(0)
```